How can Power Automate Desktop handle a new web tab who's URL changes?
I created a PAD flow that launches a website, logs in and goes to the report section and chooses the correct report from a dropdown and enters the correct fiscal year in a text box. Everything works fine up until that point where the report is generated in a new tab. The report URL always changes due to the session ID and here is where my issue starts. I cannot figure out how to get PAD to download the report from the new tab. PAD is looking for the either the URL, name of the tab or foreground window all of which I tried in my flow. When the report is open, Chrome auto switches to the report tab, after instructing PAD to click on the objects it does not do it. The mouse simply goes to the download button but does not click, the flow finishes with no errors.  The new web instance in PAD for the report does have a variable which is being used for clicking the objects to download the reports. I tried with both the first web variable and the new one, however, none seemed to work.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.
As a side note, I have to download 9 reports from the first tab. This is a government website and there are no APIs or FTPs available to retrieve these reports.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I had a very similar issue. In my case I was trying to download an invoice that opens in the new tab once a link in the original tab is clicked on. Since I was not able to find any solutions online, and since it looks like that PAD can't handle a tab that is opened this way, I came up with a workaround. Please note that 'right click' > 'copy link' and/or 'right click' > 'open link in the new window' did not work (it was not opening actual link to the document but a starting page instead).
Anyhow, the workaround:

Manually click on the link in the original tab
When the link opens in the new tab - count the number of 'tabs' needed to get to the URL
In the PAD flow, when the link opens in the new tab, use 'Send Keys' to the foreground window to send as many 'tab' keys as needed to get the URL highlighted
Use 'Send Keys' to the foreground window to copy the URL {Control}({C})
Manually launch a new browser to a starting page (such as google.com)
Count how many 'tabs' you need to get to the URL
In the PAD flow launch a new browser (I find it helpful to launch in 'Maximized' Window state), use 'Send Keys' to the foreground window to tab to the URL and then 'Send Keys' to the foreground window to send paste command {Control}({V}) and Enter {Return}
When your report opens it will be opened in the 'Browser2' instance and you can take it from there

Hope this helps.
